# Stored Proc not performing any actions

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have this stored proc

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RegisterUser$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `RegisterUser`(IN `username` VARCHAR(30), IN `password` VARCHAR(30), IN `firstname` VARCHAR(25), IN `lastname` VARCHAR(30), IN `email` VARCHAR(35))


BEGIN
INSERT INTO users
(
username,
password,
firstname,
lastname,
email
)
VALUES
(
@username,
@password,
@firstname,
@lastname,
@email
);

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Whenever i try to execute this in PHPmyadmin or from the PHP code, no records are being inserted and no errors come up. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You never set the variables `@username`, `@password`, etc.

Comment: In MySQL, variable names that start with an `@` character are **user-defined variables** (sometimes referred to as "session variables"), which are distinct (and very different) from procedure variables and parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `@` since your parameters don't have them too.

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS RegisterUser$$
CREATE PROCEDURE `RegisterUser`(IN `uname` VARCHAR(30), IN `pass` VARCHAR(30), IN `first` VARCHAR(25), IN `last` VARCHAR(30), IN `mail` VARCHAR(35))        
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO users (username, password, firstname, lastname, email)
  VALUES (uname, pass, first, last, mail);
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

And use different parameter names than your column names to avoid mistakes.